# Dynamically inject page content

Tags: 7

I'm using Drupal 7. I want to set up a dynamic page, which shows expertises' portfolios. I want to have a basic framework for that page and query data dynamically into the page.

For example, when someone goes to site/expertise?=em, they will find Em's portfolio, but when someone goes to site/expertise?=sarah, they will find Sarah's portfolio. It should be the same page, but just dynamically injected data.

Ideally the administrator will be able to upload xml or excel files and somewhere in the template will query the data from the uploaded database to update the data. Is that even possible, or are there any modules I can use?

Comment: i would take backbone.js for this in the combination with drupal...there is also a backbone module for that...but haven't tested it yet..

Comment: Backbone seems like a massive amount of overkill for this.  I would suggest just using Views and looking into either exposed or contextual filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view and add a contextual filter

Contextual filter :

[image: contextual filter]

Author filter :

[image: author_filter]

Accept the author's name in the url :

[image: author name url]

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand and I don't even know what to ask to be honest. How do I add the content for example? if I create a view and add some contextual filter, and the How do I add a new people's information like name, profile, description? Sorry I just started using view, it is still very confusing to me at the moment...